# Need to change VARCHAR format to DATETIME by MySQL

Tags: mysql

Need to change the data from the column "4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM"
VARCHAR format and convert to "2011-05-16 20:14:00" DATETIME format used by MySQL

Alter Table hourly_calories
ADD date_new DATETIME;

Update hourly_calories
Set ActivityHour = REPLACE(ActivityHour, " PM", "");

Update hourly_calories
Set ActivityHour = REPLACE(ActivityHour, " AM", "");

Update hourly_calories
Set ActivityHour = REPLACE(ActivityHour, "/", "-");

UPDATE hourly_calories
SET date_new = STR_TO_DATE(ActivityHour, '%d.%m.%Y %h:%i:%s');

I submitted a request but an error comes up:"Truncated incorrect time value: '4-12-2016 12:00:00'"

Answer (score 0):

Your value uses '-' as the separator between day, month, year, but in your STR_TO_DATE() you use '.' as the separator.

WRONG:

```
mysql> select str_to_date('4-12-2016 12:00:00', '%d.%m.%Y %h:%i:%s') as datetime;
+----------+
| datetime |
+----------+
| NULL     |
+----------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Warning (Code 1411): Incorrect datetime value: '4-12-2016 12:00:00' for function str_to_date
```

RIGHT:

```
mysql> select str_to_date('4-12-2016 12:00:00', '%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s') as datetime;
+---------------------+
| datetime            |
+---------------------+
| 2016-12-04 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+
```

I also notice you removed the AM/PM marker, so you have lost the information you need to map the time into a 24-hour clock. So all your times are going to be recorded as very early!

Comment: At the moment I can't give you points as I'm new. Thank you very much for your reply.